# How find the norm $||f_x||$ of linear functional $f_x:C[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Consider the Banach space $C[a,b]$ with sup norm. For any fixed $x\in C[a,b]$ define $f_x(y)$ for any $y \in C[a,b]$ as follows:
>   $$f_x(y)=\int_a^b x(t)y(t) dt$$
>   Show that $f_x$ is a Bounded linear functional and compute $||f_x||$ .

Comment: Do you know the Hahn-Banach Theorem? Or the Riesz Representaton theorem for $C[a,b]^*$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
|f_x(y)| = \left|\int_a^b x(t)y(t)\,dt \right| \leq \int_a^b |x(t)y(t)|\,dt
\leq \|x\|_1\|y\|_\infty ,
$$
so $\|f_x\| \leq \|x\|_1$. Now try proving that they are indeed equal.

Hint: you would like to take $y(t)=\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x(t))$.

Some more hints: call $Z=\{t:x(t)=0\}$ and for every $n\in\mathbb N$ define $y_n(t)=\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x(t))\min(n d_Z(t),1)$. Then:

- $\|y_n\|_\infty\leq1$,
- $y_n$ is $n$-Lipschitz, hence continuous,
- $y_n(t)\to\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x(t))$ pointwise,
- $f_x(y_n) = \int_a^b x(t)y_n(t)\,dt \to \int_a^b x(t)\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x(t))\,dt = \int_a^b|x(t)|\,dt = \|x\|_1$.

Edit: since a picture is worth a thousand words...

The blue line is $x(t)$, the orange line is $y_5(t)$:

[image]

Comment: But is $y(t) = \text{sign}(x(t))$ continuous, is $y(t) \in C([a, b])$?

Comment: No, of course not. Hence, you *would like* to take...

Comment: Call $Z=\{t:x(t)=0\}$ and consider $y_n(t)=\mathrm{sign}(x(t)) (n d_Z(t) \wedge 1)$.

Comment: These functions are $n$-Lip, they converge pointwise to $\mathrm{sign}(x)$ and they are dominated (by $1$).

Comment: That seems pretty complicated to me, but maybe it will work.

Comment: Why complicated? All the required checks listed above are immediate. Obvious by the definition of $y_n$. What is that you don't understand?

Comment: Hey, take it easy.  I'm not trying to be your critic, just sharing a few thoughts. Anyway, I want to think about it some more.  Cheers!

Comment: No but I'm taking it easy. I just asked what you find difficult to prove. It seems to me that the verification is immediate

Comment: OK, I'm a little busy right now, but I'll try to get back to you before too long.  Cheers!

Comment: What is $d_Z(t)$?

Comment: The distance from $Z$: $d_Z(t)=\min\{|t-s|:s\in Z\}$.

Comment: I think the function $y_n$ is not $n$-Lipchitz. Because I try see if $y_n$ is Lipchitz I obtaing 
$$|y_n(t)-y_n(u)|=| \mbox{sign}(x(t)) \mbox{min}(nd_Z(t),1)-\mbox{sign}(x(u)) \mbox{min}(nd_Z(u),1)|$$ and then by triangular inequality and by the fact that $|\mbox{sign}| \leq 1$ :
$$|y_n(t)-y_n(u)| \leq nd_Z(t)+nd_Z(u)$$ but of this one can not conclude that $|y_n(t)-y_n(u)| \leq n|t-u|$

Comment: @VictorDanielMendozaRubio It is Lipschitz. One way to see it is the following. Start by looking at $\tilde y_n(t)=\mathrm{sign}((t)) n d_Z(t)=n \tilde y_1(t)$. Do you agree that it is $n$-Lipschitz? But then, $y_n$ is simply the truncation at $-1$ and $1$: $y_n(t) = \max(\min(\tilde y_n(t),1),-1)$, so it is $n$-Lipschitz as well.

Comment: Another way is to notice that the sets $\{t:x(t)>0\}$ and $\{t:x(t)<0\}$ are open. Inside the former set, $y_n(t)=\min(nd_Z(t),1)$ is clearly $n$-Lipschitz, inside the latter, $y_n(t)=-\min(nd_Z(t),1)$ is clearly $n$-Lipschitz. Moreover, in both cases $y_n\to0$ when $t\to Z$, so the pieces can be glued together to yield an $n$-Lipschitz function

Comment: @VictorDanielMendozaRubio I've also added a picture to convince you